# What would you see while falling into Saturn's atmosphere?

Tags: saturn

So I’ve always wondered about what would happen if you fell into Saturn, would you just fall straight through since it’s a gas giant?

This is presuming we have a suit that protects us from the extreme conditions.

Comment: You could not fall straight through, the enormous pressure deep inside will kill you before you hit the rocky core.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a suit that can protect you from re-entry, extreme winds that can tear a human up, and extreme pressures and temperatures (Saturn's upper atmosphere has the same pressure of Earth at sea level, imagine how strong the pressure is in the lower atmosphere). Obviously no such suit exists. For the first few moments of the fall, you would be in the upper atmosphere and see Saturn's yellow-ish brown colour clouds below you which is made of ammonia, phosphine, water vapour. The view you would see is similar to [this](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/z5asZVB8rilNy-XDz6Icnsu1yic=/0x0:3000x1266/1200x800/filters:focal(1497x262:1977x742)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56655593/CGF_STILL_00032.0.jpg). That is (probably) what you would see as you are in the upper atmosphere where it's mainly hydrogen, helium, and a bit of ammonia crystals. Temperatures are near -250 degrees Celsius. Now, things are going to go downhill from here (literally). After that beautiful view, you'll fall into those yellow-ish brown clouds made of ammonium and now you won't see anything except for gas. And as you go deeper, it'll be darker (similar to the twilight zone in the ocean) so let's hope you have a flash light, and also pressures will get stronger. Couple of hours have passed (you're falling fast by the way) and now temperatures are getting high, near 80 degrees Celsius. It's probably pitch black by now and and now you're probably falling through molecular hydrogen (H<sub>2</sub>) and again, pressures are very high right now. You're continuing to fall and now you have reached liquid hydrogen (pressure is so strong that it forces Hydrogen into a liquid state), so by now I'm assuming you'll start to slow down and stop falling, but let's assume you don't. You're still falling and now pressures are very high, as much as 1000 x more than Earth. After falling through liquid, you'll most likely reach the solid, rocky, molten, hot core of Saturn. Basically you'll stop falling and **not** fall through Saturn. But it is most likely you won't even reach the core because of the metallic liquid hydrogen layer below the liquid H<sub>2</sub> layer as metallic hydrogen has a high density and will eventually balance the force of gravity.

So in short: While the view may be pleasant for a few minutes in the upper atmosphere, it's overall not a pleasant ride and you should prefer to stay right here on Earth.

Source: https://sciencing.com/saturns-atmosphere-compare-earths-3547.html

Comment: At what depth does the density of Saturn's atmosphere does it reach the density of water? At that point you'd presumably stop falling and start floating.

Comment: @SteveLinton At about 1000km below the clouds, you'll reach the liquid hydrogen layer. And below that is metallic liquid hydrogen. And no, you won't be able to float because liquid Hydrogen has a density of 0.0708 g/cm cubed. [Source](https://www.windows2universe.org/saturn/interior/S_int_structure_liquid.html)

Comment: The density of liquid hydrogen will vary with pressure. At some pressure it will reach the density of water.

Comment: @SteveLinton At that point, it's not liquid hydrogen anymore, it's metallic liquid hydrogen. And it becomes that at a pressure of 500 - 1500 GPa. But also you'd be falling very fast but at some point you will slow down and stop. It's most likely you won't reach the core (assuming you have a superpower suit).

Comment: The gravity of Saturn is strong near the center so I'm assuming you won't float. It's only weak at the surface at 10.44 m/s squared.

Comment: do you know that liquid hydrogen becomes metallic below the density of water? If do, I'd be interested to see a source.

Comment: strength of gravity doesn't affect whether you float or sink -- it pulls equally hard on the liquid around you.

Comment: @SteveLinton "strength of gravity doesn't affect whether you float or sink" The buoyant force equation has the standard gravity constant (9.8 m/s^2) in it meaning gravity does very much affect whether you sink or float.

Comment: @SteveLinton Metallic liquid hydrogen has a density range of 0.4 g/cc - 4 g/cc, meaning its density is below and greater than water. [Source](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01808313).

Comment: @SteveLinton "it pulls equally hard on the liquid around you". Liquid is a different state of matter meaning it needs **even more** gravity (or pressure) to condense it.

Comment: There are several misconceptions in the answer and comments. I'm busy right now (Exploring space! NASA OPAG.) but this weekend I'll write an answer with details.